# UnityRegistry.Scan vs. UnityContainer.RegisterTypes

Tags: c#, unity-container

I have an application that uses Unity. In one area of the application, the code scans the assembly to register the types (auto-registration) using this code:

```
public class CommonRegistry : UnityRegistry
{
    public CommonRegistry()
    {
        const StringComparison strCmp = StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase;

        Register<ITenantStore, TenantStore>();

        Scan(scanner =>
        {
            scanner.AssembliesInBaseDirectory(asm => asm.GetName().Name.StartsWith(@"Infrastructure", strCmp));
            scanner.ForRegistries();
        });                       
    }
}
```

The above code uses the UnityRegistry class of the UnityConfiguration assembly.

But in the Unity documentation, the example shows this code:

unityContainer.RegisterTypes(AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies(), ...

What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 0):

I think its same with here.
[register dependency Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46770190/register-dependency-unity)
the difference is the UnityRegistry is for lower versions.
while the other one is for 3.5 up.
but both are to register dependencies.

Comment: Could you elaborate it more?