# register dependency Unity

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, dependencies, unity-container

I just want to ask if there's a way to register dependencies in a simpliest way using unity.

```
    public class Module : IModule
    {
        IUnityContainer _container;
        IRegionManager _regionManager;

    public Module (IUnityContainer container, IRegionManager regionManager)
    {
        _container = container;
        _regionManager = regionManager;
    }

    public void initialize()
    {
      IRegion region = _regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.ContentRegion];
       _container.RegisterType<"InterfaceHERE", "CLASSHERE">();
    }
```

I do have 30-40 classes and interfaces, and I don't want to code it redundant. Are there any ways to code it in the simplest form? Like getting all classes and make a loop and register it?

Thanks!

Comment: If you are using Service Locator pattern instead of actual IoC then you can call `Resolve()` on any type with a public constructor and Unity will find it without previously registering it. Hopefully though you are actually using IoC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Unity 3.0 you can register your implementations in container using convention. Please [see the details here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn507479(v=pandp.30).aspx), the code looks like below. You have to specify which types you want to auto-register, how (choose mapping), decide on their names and life time.

```
using (var container = new UnityContainer())
{
  container.RegisterTypes(
    AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies(),
    WithMapping.MatchingInterface,
    WithName.Default,
    WithLifetime.ContainerControlled);
}
```

If you are using Unity 2.0, then you have to use additional packages, see the nuget [UnityConfiguration](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnityConfiguration). Using this package you can scan for implementations and auto register them as below, please check the project documentation for details:

```
public class FooRegistry : UnityRegistry
{

    (...)

    Scan(scan =>
    {
            scan.AssembliesInBaseDirectory();
            scan.ForRegistries();
            scan.With<FirstInterfaceConvention>();
            scan.With<AddAllConvention>()
                .TypesImplementing<IHaveManyImplementations>();
            scan.With<SetAllPropertiesConvention>().OfType<ILogger>();
            scan.ExcludeType<FooService>();
    });
}
```

Comment: I think its for v3.5 and higher. I'm only at 2.0

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer to cover Unity 2.0 also, good luck! If my post is helpful, please mark it as an answer, it'll help others.

Comment: after installing unityconfiguration, still can't find RegisterTypes extension. :(

Comment: @EnricoDomingo RegisterTypes is only for Unity >= 3.0, it's built there. For UnityConfiguration package the flow is a bit different, I've added a code from their documentation, check out their github.

Comment: Thanks @Michał Żołnieruk!